Go back in time in Latin?
I translate "go back in time" into Latin as "redire in tempus". It sounds good for me. However, is there any author who ever wrote such sentence or an equivalent about going back in time? I just want to know if there's something in the Latin literature. I Googled but I found nothing as always

Can you explain what you want to say with "go back in time"? Just to make sure, are you referring to time travel?

Is there another meaning in English? Go back in time to change, avoid something. That's what I've learnt.

I figured as much, but it's always helpful to clarify in case there is any confusion (such as mistranslations, misunderstandings, etc.).

If that's the case, then the suggestion redire in tempus seems off, because in the English expression "go back in time," when referring to the idea of time-travel, "in time" means "with respect to time, in the temporal dimension," etc. That said, while I could think of an expression or two that may sound less "off," I'm not aware how the Romans expressed this idea, if it ever crossed their minds.

I would say ad tempus is more appropriate for "in time, in due time, at the right time" (in tempus being more like "for a time").
For example, Cic. Att. 13, 45:

… nisi me Torquati causa teneret satis erat dierum ut Puteolos excurrere possem et ad tempus redire.
If the matter of Torquatus weren't preventing me, I would have enough days to make an excursion to Puteoli and come back in time.


So, from OP's comment, it seems he's referring to time travel, rather than someone returning "in (due) time."

@Sebastian Koppehel: With ref. to cmw's comment, would "retro ire ad tempus" be of any use?

@tony I guess it might be "of any use," depending on context, I could imagine something like Si ad pristinum tempus redire possem &c. – or should it be in tempus? I don't know, and I'm not aware of any Roman saying something like that – I suspect they would have expressed the whole sentiment differently.
